# Can VueJS components be passed an expression/function to run?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

First of all, please go easy on me, I'm new to Vue and still trying to understand it but I'm experienced in Angular.

I'm trying to find the Vue equivelant of this code, which uses an Angular-UI component...

```
<uib-datepicker date-disabled="myController.isDateDisabled(day)"></uib-datepicker>
```

and in the controller:

```
vm.isDateDidabled = function(day){
    return (day === 7); // Example test for Sundays
};
```

The component uses a passed expression from your controller using a '&' binding and runs it when it needs to. I haven't seen this done in Vue yet. Can this be done with props?

Comment: https://vuejs.org/v2/api/#v-bind

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Absolutely.

Lets take your example - we have a datepicker:

`<date-picker></date-picker>`

Vue components can recieve [props](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Props). If we wanted to give the date picker component a "disabled" prop it would look this this:

`<date-picker v-bind:disabled="true"></date-picker>`

When you use the `v-bind` directive, the expression inside the quotes is evaluated as javascript, with the assumed context being the component whose template this is.

So if we have a component:

```
Vue.component('parent', {
  methods: {
    isDisabled (day) {
      return day === 7
    }
  }
})
```

You can simply execute that method to get the value for the prop (this will be re-evaluated every time the component renders).

`<date-picker v-bind:disabled="isDisabled(5)"></date-picker>`

Comment: Not that you should do this but just to assist in the notion anything in the quotes is javascript. You could put the `day === 7` in there instead of the method call and it would eval as the return statement.

Comment: Thank you, great answer.